# eclipse: add Chrome extension library

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In Eclipse, static html project:
Developing Chrome extension, it would be nice to have IntelliSense om methods.

Is it possible to add a library to eclipse, so you would have IntelliSense when creating chrome extensions?

Thanks
Rregards
Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I could think of doing this would to be install the Eclipse Aptana plug-in, then you would have to find a Rubble that supported the chrome* API.  I don't think you will find anything though.  The API is actually very small.

I would just use the online docs...